# Forcing bazel _not_ to statically embed external dependencies?

Tags: bazel, packaging

I'm investigating the use of bazel to build some of my software. Unfortunately, I think I've come across a show-stopping issue, which is that bazel binaries can't be packaged for distributions like Debian.

The issue is that bazel is very keen on downloading external dependencies as source code and then compiling and linking them into the resulting binary. The protobuf libraries are an example of this. This is strictly forbidden for most Linux (and other) distributions; legally packaged binaries need to link to the system libraries rather than embedding their own copies.

I suspect there's no easy fix for this and that I'll just have to give up on bazel, but on the off-chance that anyone's thought about this: is there one? I think this would need something like the ability to prevent certain external dependencies being fetched, instead replacing them with local placeholder copies. For example, for the protobuf case I'd need to make sure that somehow tell bazel that any attempt to download `com_github_protocolbuffers_protobuf` should instead use a local version I had made which used the system library. Of course, this would also require telling bazel to ignore the hash, which is terrible...

Comment: At this level of discussion, you probably should also reach out to bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com. The short answer is that yes it's possible (bazel uses locally-installed C++ toolchains, for example), but a lot of things are set up by default to download dependencies. E.g. if you follow the first "Getting Started" for rules_proto, it uses an `http_archive`, which is of course going to download things. If you want to use locally installed libraries, you'll need different WORKSPACE rules.

Comment: They usually direct questions here, but yeah, that's worth a try.